# Angular Material - Reduce horizontal gap between fields in flex Layout

Tags: javascript, html, angular, flexbox

Can somebody please help me to reduce the gap between fields in Angular Material using fxLayout.
I am trying to place 5 fields in one row but for some reason the last feild goes on the next line. If I reduce the gap between the fields then I can fit them in one row.

Below is my code

```
    <span class="gene-block">Barcode dimensions</span>
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div >
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="X-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeX"
                   (change)='barcodeXChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Y-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeY"
                   (change)='barcodeYChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Width"
                   formControlName="barcodeWidth"
                   (change)='barcodeWidthChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field  fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Height"
                   formControlName="barcodeHeight"
                   (change)='barcodeHeightChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Present look and feel
[image]

Reducing the flFlex from 50 to 20 just reduces the field size but not the gap. On the contrary the gap increases more.
[image]

Adding  above to each of the <mat-form-field
increase the width of the fields such that it goes outside of the main frame. Please see below screenshot
[image]

Comment: try `fxFlex="20"` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="gene-block">Barcode dimensions</span>
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" fxFlex="100">
    <div fxFlex="20">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="X-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeX"
                   (change)='barcodeXChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div  fxFlex="20">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Y-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeY"
                   (change)='barcodeYChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="20">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Width"
                   formControlName="barcodeWidth"
                   (change)='barcodeWidthChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="20">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Height"
                   formControlName="barcodeHeight"
                   (change)='barcodeHeightChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove `fxFelx` from `<mat-form-field>` & add in above `<div>`

Comment: You need to reduce the fxFlex to 18 or less or just share code with stackbliz link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75tyyi?file=src/app.component.html

Comment: you have not given proper code in component.ts file no form found

Comment: provide running code.

Comment: My apologies, I have just provided the component html file as I could not mange to get all the 3rd party lib into them.Hope that will be hellpful

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gry8pp?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts find working demo

Comment: still having issue then let me know

Answer (score -1):

To reduce the gap between the fields in Angular Material using fxLayout, you can add the fxLayoutGap attribute to the div containing the mat-form-field elements. This attribute sets the gap between the child elements inside the container.

In your code, you can modify the div containing the mat-form-field elements to include the fxLayoutGap attribute:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <div>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="X-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeX"
                   (change)='barcodeXChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Y-axis"
                   formControlName="barcodeY"
                   (change)='barcodeYChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Width"
                   formControlName="barcodeWidth"
                   (change)='barcodeWidthChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field  fxFlex="50">
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Height"
                   formControlName="barcodeHeight"
                   (change)='barcodeHeightChange($event)'>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code above, fxLayoutGap="10px" sets the gap between the child elements inside the div to 10 pixels. You can adjust this value to suit your needs. With this modification, the fields should be placed in one row without the last field going to the next line.

Hope this could help!